# How to transition from Glacier storage class to Deep Archive storage class?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

Their documentation claims this is possible:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html

"You can transition from the GLACIER storage class to the DEEP_ARCHIVE storage class."

But it doesn't appear to be working. I created a lifecycle rule to transition to Deep Archive, and uploaded a test file to Standard storage class. Only the Standard file was transitioned. My existing files in Glacier were not.

How do I transition existing files in Glacier to Deep Archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you need to make sure you lifecycle rule is enabled. Select the rule and click Actions, then select Enable lifecycle rule.

There is no clear visual indicator that a rule is disabled (it is not greyed out, doesn't have a strikethrough, doesn't have the text "disabled" anywhere). It just has a purple circle on the left, of unknown meaning. When you enable the rule, a white checkmark appears in said purple circle, and the background of the circle also darkens slightly.